# Get custom payload from FCM in android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to read below mentioned keys from FCM Push notification.

```
    { 
      "from_id": "",
      "data": {  
        "sender_id": "15", 
        "receiver_id": "42", 
        "sender_name": "Addy", 
        "alert": "Addy sent you a message.",
        "notification_type": "message",
        "message": "testing" 
              }
     }
```

I am using

```
      public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

      String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("sender_name");

      sendNotification(title, "");

      }
```

Problem is `title=remoteMessage.getData.get("sender_name"); returns null` , and when I view in browser it shows me that data is present in `sender_name`.

Comment: Though i can't solve it since i have started with firebase but i can tell you where to find a solution cause it helped me a lot. Here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @SameerKhan1406  I am trying this
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                String title = json.getString("sender_name");

but i am receiving JSONException. " No value for sender_name". But in logcat i can see the value against Data PayLoad: tag.

Comment: Get json object in response rather getting individual data then use json.getString("sender_name");
share your code i'll help you tomorrow throughout ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
   if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }
```