# How to send parameters in push notifications?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm trying to send some hidden parameters along with the notification message sent to the user, used to open specific form with specific ID.
I know we have "tags" to categorize the users we want to send the message to including the userid.
That's not what I need.
What I'm looking for is:
after the push notification is sent to user, I need my app to able to read some parameters used to open the right form with the right data displayed in.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: There is a huge amount of documentation on Notification payloads for different platforms and Notification frameworks.  Your question is pretty broad and difficult to answer in detail without writing a novel.

Comment: Thank you @Jason. Actually I searched a lot but found nothing. I don't want a novel or huge documentation, all I need is some hints on how it could be done. PS:  I'm using Xamarin Forms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834581/ios-push-notification-custom-format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583248/get-custom-payload-from-fcm-in-android

Comment: Thank you @Jason that is exactly what I need. It is weird that I searched a lot but never found similar solution that I could play with this json message the way I want. Peace.